# Явный вызов деструктора в классе

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
using std::cout;
using std::endl;

class Function
{
protected:
    double x;
public:
    Function(double x) {
        this->x = x;
    }
    double GetX() {
        return this->x;
    }
    void SetX() {
        cout << "Enter x:" << endl;
        std::cin >> this->x;
    }
    double valueIn() {
        return 2 * x + 3; 
    }
    void show() {
        cout << valueIn() << endl;
    }
};

class Hyperbola: public Function 
{
private:
    double k;

    Hyperbola(double x,double k): Function(x) {
        this->x = x;
        if (this->x == 0) {
            cout << "x can't be zero" << endl;
            //тут явный вызов деструктора
        }
    }
    double valueIn(){
        return 5 / x;
    }
};
int main() {
    return 0;
}
```

У меня есть класс `Function` и `Hyperbola`, который наследует `Function`. Поскольку формула гиперболы `k / x`, то делаю проверку `x == 0` и в случае, если `х==0` удаляю этот объект. Как мне явно вызвать деструктор в классе?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В конструкторе класса наверное лучше всего бросить исключение

```
class Hyperbola: public Function 
{
private:
    double k;

    Hyperbola(double x,double k): Function(x) {
        if (this->x == 0) {
            throw "x can't be zero";
        }

        this->x = x;
    }

    double valueIn(){
        return 5 / x;
    }
};
```

P.S.

кстати, а зачем вам этот код в конструкторе:

```
this->x = x;
```

если это и так происходит в родителе

```
: Function(x)
```

Comment: Лучше что-то типа `throw std::runtime_error("x can't be zero");`.

Comment: ну это да, я просто про то, что не дать конструктору закончить работу - это вроде как только выброска исключения

Comment: С этим согласен. :)